# get function execution complete percentage

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-progressbar

I'm trying to use [jQuery UI Progress Bar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/) to show the complete status of the execution of a function, but before I could even use the Progress Bar, I need to find out how many percent of my function execution is complete and send that value to the Progress Bar.

How do I find out the percentage of completeness of the execution of a php function?

Any idea please?

Thank you

Comment: What is the function doing? Are there external parameters that can be quantified? For instance, if it's inserting rows into a table, one could check the progress periodically. If there are none, you'll have to create them.

Comment: The function is inserting stuff in a database, checking user permissions, etc, but I want a solution that works for ANY kind of function, no matter what the function is doing

Comment: Cannot be done. One cannot *peek* into a PHP process to gauge its progress. There **must** be something external -- specifically set by that function -- to check.

Comment: ok, something external like what?

Comment: Like counting the number of table rows inserted so far (against a total stored somewhere else). Or a file written to periodically with something indicating its progress.

Comment: Ok I see, so I basically have to calculate the percentage number myself based on what my function is doing

Answer (score 0):

Increment a variable that is unique to the session in a database or file that is accessible to both scripts. You can use the `session_id()` function to get a good unique key, then store in a database table the current progress value and retrieve that value to display your your progress bar value. The increment rate of the progress value will be dependent on what your script is doing and how frequently you want to update the progress bar.